# Flutter: My PageView.builder is not reloading when I update the list from which it's built

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a "Reel" screen (picture tiktok) where I use a pageview.builder to build the content from a list of 'Content' objects. Everything displays as expected and what not but the problem comes when I use the 'hide' functionality on the various objects. If I choose to hide a post, I expect that once the back end functionality is complete (which is working as expected), then the actual page that is in view will disappear to show the next item but that is not happening (well not quite). What happens is it removes the subsequent reel, still showing the item that was intended to be removed. However when I leave the screen and return, the proper reel is now hidden and the others show as normal. This issue is only happening when I decide to hide the first reel. If i scroll to the next reel and use hide, then it works as expected.

Here is my pageview builder class:

```
class ReelWheelBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReelWheelBuilder({
    super.key,
    required this.mediaList,
  });

  final List<Content> mediaList;

  @override
  State<ReelWheelBuilder> createState() => _ReelWheelBuilderState();
}

class _ReelWheelBuilderState extends State<ReelWheelBuilder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final reels = widget.mediaList;
    return reels.isEmpty
        ? const EmptyReelPlaceholder()
        : PageView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: reels.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ReelWheel(
                mediaItem: reels[index],
              );
            });
  }
}
```

and the hide function call:

```
void showFlagContentOptions(String postId) {
// Show Flag content modal
CustomFeedback.bottomSheet(
  context: context,
  content: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        left: defaultPaddingX,
        right: defaultPaddingX,
        top: defaultPaddingY),
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: [
        Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: defaultPaddingY,
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SettingTile(
                label: 'Hide',
                leading: const Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.eyeSlash,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  auProvider.updateHiddenPosts(postId);
                },
              ),
              const CustomDivider(),
              SettingTile(
                label: 'Report',
                leading: const Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.triangleExclamation,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  // pop bottom sheet
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  // show new bottom sheet with Report parameters
                  displayReportOptions(postId);
                  // send report reasons and post id to api
                  // display feedback confirming report sent and handled in 24 hours
                  // provide option for user to block user or hide post
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

I am using a Consumer to fetch and pass the media list to the ReelWheelBuilder class so it updates automatically when the item is hidden but the actual view just does not seem to update.

Comment: what you do on updateHiddenPosts, just remove the reel from your local list or send a postId to the server and remove it from there as well? if yes you do remove it from the servers as well then do you refetch the updated list??

Comment: @pixel updateHiddenPosts adds this current post id to a list of hidden posts attached to the current server then it syncs with the server.

Comment: Make sure your provider calls notifylisteners();

Comment: @Mearaj I am calling it once I update the hidden post list and it's rebuilding the consumer that's wrapping the PageView builder but it won't remove the post in the rebuild even though through debugging I can see that there is one less post in the list.

Comment: @FevtheDev, Also if you are using provider instance like final MyProvider provider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context); then make sure its like this way --> final MyProvider provider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context,listen: true);

Comment: @Mearaj So I'm accessing the provider instance through a consumer and I'm thinking it will listen automatically?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it should listen automatically in Consumer.

Comment: I am now trying to reproduce the issue using your code. If answer is found, then will post it and if any issues like it requires more parts of the code, I will let you know.

Comment: Your code is not actually enough to try. Can you provide the two important parts needed?. One is how are you using Provider code and other is the implementation of auProvider.updateHiddenPosts method.
It will help resolving the issue.